# views with different content types case studies

Tags: views, 6

For my first Drupal site ever I was thinking of filling the frontpage with a view that has different content types. I'm even mixing page content type with a custom event content type so now I have problems with styling the view because of different content fields in different view items.

Does anybody know of case studies where people have succesfully mixed custom with stock content types because this is becoming a nightmare.

Comment: This is a question and answer site. I am not sure what exactly you are asking here. You should clarify what exactly the problem is that you're having, displaying multiple content types is not a problem per se.

Comment: Well my question is do you know of any case studies that have tackled creating views with different content types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views gives you enough power to maintain your custom styling. Please check for Views for `theme information`.

You can theme your different fields, rows, general theme.

You can style your node.tpl.php for general and for specific type node-[type].tpl.php

Comment: Yes I was thinking of using if statements in a template file attached to the view but that may result in more cumbersome way of going about it. For now I found a way around it so I could move on. Probably get back to later